# Universal lib which is having other libs inside without x86 support

Tags: ios, iphone

I have  iOS lib as a universal library and lipo -info confirms the same. But still not working on simulator as few of the component/lib used inside my universal lib are not having x86 arch support so my doubt on it. If there is a lib which uses another libs , all used libs inside main lib should have arch x86 support?